# Gunicorn / Nginx / Django :(

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have deployed my django app on ubunto below status seems ok but website is not running, please guide

Nginx status

> nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
> nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Gunicorn status

> ● gunicorn.socket - gunicorn socket
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.socket; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: active (listening) since Tue 2022-09-20 11:31:47 CEST; 1h 16min ago
> Triggers: ● gunicorn.service
> Listen: /run/gunicorn.sock (Stream)
> Tasks: 0 (limit: 19140)
> Memory: 0B
> CGroup: /system.slice/gunicorn.socket

website showing only

[website status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3p4W.png)

Comment: You will need to show your Nginx configuration.

Comment: 403? Forbidden? if yes then open nginx.conf and enter value of user. the one which displayed in terminal `user ubuntu` and then restart nginx

Comment: `Nginx configuration
server {  
 listen 80;     
 server_name ;    
 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }    
 location /static/ {         
  root /feddi/threshold;     
 }    
 location / {         
  include proxy_params;         
  proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;     
 }
}`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, `proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock` makes no sense whatsover. It should be just `proxy_pass /run/gunicorn.sock`.